# Extract capture group matches from regular expressions? (or: where is gregexec?)

Tags: regex, r, backreference

Given a regular expression containing [capture groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (parentheses) and a string, how can I obtain *all* the substrings matching the capture groups, i.e., the substrings usually referenced by "\1", "\2"?

Example: consider a regex capturing digits preceded by "xy":

```
s <- "xy1234wz98xy567"

r <- "xy(\\d+)"
```

Desired result:

```
[1] "1234" "567"
```

First attempt: `gregexpr`:

```
regmatches(s,gregexpr(r,s))
#[[1]]
#[1] "xy1234" "xy567"
```

Not what I want because it returns the substrings matching the entire pattern.

Second try: `regexec`:

```
regmatches(s,regexec("xy(\\d+)",s))
#[[1]]
#[1] "xy1234" "1234"
```

Not what I want because it returns *only* the first occurence of a matching for the entire pattern and the capture group.

If there was a `gregexec` function, extending `regexec` as `gregexpr` extends `regexpr`, my problem would be solved.

So the question is: how to retrieve all substrings (or indices that can be passed to `regmatches` as in the examples above) matching capture groups in an arbitrary regular expression?

Note: the pattern for `r` given above is just a silly example, it must remain arbitrary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not sure about doing this in base, but here's a package for your needs:

```
library(stringr)

str_match_all(s, r)
#[[1]]
#     [,1]     [,2]  
#[1,] "xy1234" "1234"
#[2,] "xy567"  "567"
```

Many `stringr` functions also have parallels in base R, so you can also achieve this without using `stringr`.

For instance, here's a simplified version of how the above works, using base R:

```
sapply(regmatches(s,gregexpr(r,s))[[1]], function(m) regmatches(m,regexec(r,m)))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. I'll check its source. I believe there is (or should be) a solution in base R, given that this is a basic task.

Comment: It just uses `lapply` and `regexec` (though cleverly)... Just type `str_match_all` and `str_match` to see this...

Answer (score 12):

For a base R solution, what about just using `gsub()` to finish processing the strings extracted by `gregexpr()` and `regmatches()`?

```
s <- "xy1234wz98xy567"
r <- "xy(\\d+)"

gsub(r, "\\1", regmatches(s,gregexpr(r,s))[[1]])
# [1] "1234" "567"
```

Comment: Nice trick, but It may fail if, for instance, the capture group is inside a lookaround (`perl=TRUE`).

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft -- Would you give an example? I'm thinking that lookarounds aren't captured, so am not being able to see what you mean.

Comment: Consider this: `r <- "xy(?=(\\d+))"; gsub(r, "\\1", regmatches(s,gregexpr(r,s,perl=TRUE))[[1]], perl=TRUE); gsub(r, "\\1", s, perl=TRUE)`. Note that `gsub` (alone) can retrive the digits in `\1`.

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft -- Interesting to see that they are indeed captured (even if they aren't 'eaten up' by the regex algorithm).

Answer (score 8):

`strapplyc` in the [gsubfn package](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) does that:

```
> library(gsubfn)
>
> strapplyc(s, r)
[[1]]
[1] "1234" "567"
```

Try `?strapplyc` for additional info and examples.

**Related Functions**

**1)** A generalization of `strapplyc` is `strapply` in the same package.  It takes a function which inputs the captured portions of each match and returns the output of the function.  When the function is `c` it reduces to `strapplyc`.  For example, suppose we wish to return results as numeric:

```
> strapply(s, r, as.numeric)
[[1]]
[1] 1234  567
```

**2)** `gsubfn` is another related function in the same package.  It is like `gsub` except the replacement string can be a replacement function (or a replacement list or a replacement proto object).  The replacement function inputs the captured portions and outputs the replacement.  The replacement replaces the match in the input string.  If a formula is used, as in this example, the right hand side of the formula is regarded as the function body.  In this example we replace the match with `XY{#}` where # is twice the matched input number.

```
> gsubfn(r, ~ paste0("XY{", 2 * as.numeric(x), "}"), s)
[1] "XY{2468}wz98XY{1134}"
```

**UPDATE:**  Added `strapply` and `gsubfn` examples.

Comment: This is great. One question: does `strapplyc` call `regexec` in a loop, like `stringr::str_match_all`?

Comment: `strapplyc` uses underlying code written in tcl (a string processing language) to enable it to handle very large strings and for speed (unless the `engine=` argument specifies a different engine).  See `?strapplyc` for details.

Comment: Thank you a lot for this answer. I accepted eddi's because he is correct and answered first.

Answer (score 0):

Since R 4.1.0, there is `gregexec`:

```
regmatches(s,gregexec(r,s))[[1]][2, ]
[1] "1234" "567"
```