# Splitting a string with a number in the end in R

Tags: regex, r, split

How can I split a string which contains a number (of unknown number of digits) into two strings - the number and the rest of the string. Notice that there could be other numbers in the string which should not be affected. For example:

```
"abc665abc12"   -> "abc665abc", "12"
"abc665abc 182" -> "abc665abc", "182"
"abc665abc0"    -> "abc665abc", "0"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may also use `strsplit`

```
> x = c("abc665abc12", "abc665abc 182", "abc665abc0")
> strsplit(x, "(?<=[A-Za-z])\\s*(?=\\d+$)", perl = TRUE)
[[1]]
[1] "abc665abc" "12"       

[[2]]
[1] "abc665abc" "182"      

[[3]]
[1] "abc665abc" "0"
```

Answer (score 6):

This works:

```
# op's example
x = c("abc665abc12", "abc665abc 182", "abc665abc0")

library(stringi)
res = stri_match_first_regex(x, "^(.*?) ?([0-9]+)$")


     [,1]            [,2]        [,3] 
[1,] "abc665abc12"   "abc665abc" "12" 
[2,] "abc665abc 182" "abc665abc" "182"
[3,] "abc665abc0"    "abc665abc" "0"
```

Your desired parts are in columns 2 & 3, corresponding to the parentheses in the regex.

Comment: For those seeking a way of extracting capture groups (the things in parentheses) in base, good luck. It is a real mess: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18620944/1191259

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to things like this, I like using `strapply` from the [**gsubfn**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gsubfn/index.html) package:

```
library(gsubfn)
strapply('abc665abc12', '(.*?) *(\\d+)$', c)[[1]]
# [1] "abc665abc" "12"
```

If you have a character vector, it's the same concept:

```
strapply(x, '(.*?) *(\\d+)$', c)
```

Comment: Or in base R `strsplit(sub(' *(\\d+)$', ' \\1', x), ' ', fixed = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2):

In base:

```
cbind(x,
      gsub("[ 0-9]+$", "", x), 
      gsub("^[a-z 0-9]+[a-z ]+", "", x))

     x                                
[1,] "abc665abc12"   "abc665abc" "12" 
[2,] "abc665abc 182" "abc665abc" "182"
[3,] "abc665abc0"    "abc665abc" "0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using good old regex :with two of your character vectors

```
    x <-"abc665abc12"
    y <- "abc665abc 182"
    patterns<-"[[:digit:]]+$"
    m1 <- regexpr(patterns,x) 
    m2 <-regexpr(patterns,y)
```

now `regmatches(x,m1)` yield "12" n `regmatches(y,m1)` yields "182"